# Did Siad Barre condemn atheism?

Tags: politics

The Wikipedia entry about [Islam in Somalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_in_Somalia) contains an unsourced assertion:

> The position of religious leaders changed substantially after the 1969 revolution and the introduction of scientific socialism. Siad Barre insisted that his version of socialism was compatible with Qur'anic principles, and **he condemned atheism.**

Did [Siad Barre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siad_Barre) condemn atheism?

Comment: That portion is not unsourced. It comes from reference 20: http://memory.loc.gov/master/frd/frdcstdy/so/somaliacountryst00metz_0/somaliacountryst00metz_0.pdf. See page 94 near the bottom: "Siad Barre insisted that
his version of socialism was compatible with Quranic principles,
and he condemned atheism." If you're skeptical of that source, let us know.

Comment: @called2voyage the wiki article is supposed to have a reference added to each paragraph in the form of [x].

Comment: [General references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citing_sources#General_references) are technically allowed, but they are usually reworked into inline citations later. In this case, it probably does need it though since it is word-for-word from the original.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin an 1988 reference says "The Somali people should therefore come together fight and liberate themselves from the atheist government of Siad Barre." https://books.google.com/books?id=D95VAAAAYAAJ&q=%22Siad+Barre+%22+atheism&dq=%22Siad+Barre+%22+atheism&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiznPWRnOXQAhVlyFQKHXzAACgQ6AEIGjAA

Comment: @DavePhD That sounds highly biased. Also, it is technically possible to condemn atheism and simultaneously institute it.

Comment: @called2voyage yes, there is some discussion here "Siad Barre and Mengistu were both undercover Atheists" https://www.somalinet.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=377195

Comment: @DavePhD I'm not sure I buy that myself. Sounds like a bogeyman. Easier to blame his actions on atheism than to figure out why a well-intentioned Muslim would do what he did.

Comment: @DavePhD Socialism is kind of linked to atheism.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin Not really, *communism* is often linked to atheism. Socialism in general is adopted to a greater or lesser extent by people of varied religious backgrounds.

Comment: @called2voyage Isn't communism a form of socialism?

Comment: Yes, therefore applying attributes of communism to socialism in general is poor logic. Applying attributes of socialism in general to communism, on the other hand would be ok if communism is a true subset of socialism.